# Formatting two different dates using single function

Tags: jquery, html, css

Format1 : **12-May-2014**
Format2 : **Mon-12-May-2014**

Here is my try

```js
function formatDate(date) {
    var weekday = new Array(7);

    weekday[0] = "Sun";
    weekday[1] = "Mon";
    weekday[2] = "Tue";
    weekday[3] = "Wed";
    weekday[4] = "Thu";
    weekday[5] = "Fri";
    weekday[6] = "Sat";

    var monthNames = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
    "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];

    var month = (date.getMonth()) + 1;

    month = "0" + month;
    month = month.slice(-2);

    //var out = weekday[date.getDay()] + " " + monthNames[date.getMonth()] + " " + date.getDate() + " " + date.getFullYear();
    var out = +date.getDate() + " " + weekday[date.getDay()];

    return out;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at [MomentJS](http://www.momentjs.com/), it offers several functions to easily handle these kind of issues.

Comment: Please take a MomentJS :)

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript's `new Date()` function is very smart in accepting dates in several formats.

I love **[10 ways to format time and date using JavaScript](http://www.webdevelopersnotes.com/tips/html/10_ways_to_format_time_and_date_using_javascript.php3)** and **[Working with Dates](http://www.elated.com/articles/working-with-dates/)**

Basically, you have three methods and you have to combine the strings for yourself:

```
getDate() // Returns the date
getMonth() // Returns the month
getFullYear() // Returns the year
```

**Example**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var d = new Date();
    var curr_date = d.getDate();
    var curr_month = d.getMonth() + 1; //Months are zero based
    var curr_year = d.getFullYear();
    document.write(curr_date + "-" + curr_month + "-" + curr_year);
</script>
```

via - Haim

Comment: thanks for your feed back Gagan. plz check my script. Is possible to decale var out like another varible?